# sql commands to fetch the users who didn't offerd any rides in carpooling databasel schema

Tags: mysql, sql, rdbms

Carpooling Database Schema
[image: Carpooling Database Schema]

The users in ride_users table are also the ride provider in RIDE table.
I have to identify the users details from user_details table who didn't offered any ride i.e they are not ride provider.

tried this but didn't get desired results.

```
select r1.user_id, u.*
from ride_users r1, user_details u
where r1.user_id <> (select distinct r1.user_id 
                     from ride_users r1 , ride r2 
                     where r1.ride_id = r2.ride_id 
                     and r1.user_id = r2.ride_provider_id
                     group by r1.user_id);`
```

Comment: I cannot copy/paste an image into my MySQL to create the table structure and test an answer!! So always if its text, post it as text

Comment: It means you need data of all users who are not present in ride table?

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (**without errors**), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) [Why are images of text, code and mathematical expressions discouraged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320052/266284) ERD text is DDL. [mre] [ask] [Help]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Left join and check for null to see whether the entity present in the second table.

```
SELECT u.*
FROM user_details u
LEFT JOIN ride r ON u.user_id = r.ride_provider_id
WHERE r.ride_provider_id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, it sounds like this is what you want:

```
SELECT u.*
FROM user_details u
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ride_users r1 
    WHERE r1.user_id = u.user_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct query which I wrote and tested against the real time system can be:

```
SELECT * FROM USER_DETAILS
WHERE USER_ID NOT IN 
(
SELECT RIDE_PROVIDER_ID FROM RIDE 
WHERE RIDE_PROVIDER_ID = USER_ID
);
```